# .htaccess RewriteRule with existing file and folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My web structure looks like this:

```
public_html/
    /images/
        /user/
             /userimage1.jpg
             /userimage2.jpg
             /userimage3.jpg
        /icons/
    /index.php
    /user.php
...
```

I have 2 domains: `example.com` and `images.example.com` and I want to use a `.htaccess RewriteRule` that the `images.example.com` subdomain leads to the `/images/`-folder but also to use URLs without the file extension.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /images/$1 [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, `https://example.com/user/` works fine, but when I try to open `https://images.example.com/user/userimage1.jpg` it says that `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/images/redirect:/images/user.php/userimage1.jpg`

Unfortunately, both, the domain and the subdomain have to be installed with `public_html` as the root folder.

How do I have to adept my `.htaccess` file so that both URLs, `https://example.com/user/` and `https://images.example.com/user/userimage1.jpg` work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conflict with `MultiViews` (which you've enabled at the top). The fact that "`https://example.com/user/` works fine" (with a trailing slash) is because of MultiViews, not because of your mod_rewrite directives. (The mod_rewrite directives as written would only "work" with `/user` - no trailing slash.)

When you request `https://images.example.com/user/userimage1.jpg`, MultiViews triggers an internal subrequest for `/user.php/userimage1.jpg` (`/user.php` with additional path-info `/userimage1.jpg`), but mod_rewrite has also tried to rewrite the request (an *internal* "redirect") - hence the seemingly malformed rewrite.

Generally, you need to avoid using MultiViews with mod_rewrite rewrites - a common cause of conflict.

Try the following instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite images subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /images/$1 [L]

# Append .php file extensions
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Note that I've included the trailing slash in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and taken this out of the capturing subpattern - this is assuming that the trailing slash is mandatory on your URLs (as in your example).

You don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper unless mod_rewrite really is optional? (It's not.)

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation :) Now it works fine!